# Python Flask posting large file to api

Tags: python, flask

I am building my first api using python flask and the client would be posting images to the api.  While the api works perfectly for smaller files 50kb size, it throws error while uploading 500kb - 2mb files.  I have read many posts here as well as other blogs and github issues and I understand that the server throws the error as it gets timed out before receiving the complete file.

Some of the options that I came across were:

1. using `from requests_toolbelt.multipart import encoder` and use encoder.MultipartEncoder to encode the image.
2. add `app.config['MAX_CONTENT_LENGTH'] = 100 * 1024 * 1024` to the server.py - which I did and this did not help.

The current api does not use wsgi or nginx (frankly i don't know how to use them or their purpose and currently testing my api for response) and runs on debugging mode.

My client is as follows:

***client.py***

```
import requests
from requests_toolbelt.multipart import encoder

session = requests.Session()
with open('124430597.jpg', 'rb') as f:
    files = encoder.MultipartEncoder({
        "image_data": ("124430597.jpg", f, "application/octet-stream"),
        "composite": "NONE",
    })
    url = 'http://10.7.104.57:5000/julytest'
    headers = {"Prefer": "respond-async", "Content-Type": files.content_type}
    resp = session.get(url, headers=headers, data=files)
    print(resp.text)
```

***server.py***

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from PIL import Image
import io
import requests
import numpy as np
import os
from os.path import basename
from flask import Flask, flash, request, redirect, url_for,jsonify, make_response
from werkzeug.utils import secure_filename
from flaskext.mysql import MySQL
from imagesearch.cbir import HSVDescriptor
from imagesearch.cbir import Searcher
import MySQLdb
import datetime
import cv2

UPLOAD_FOLDER = '/home/magesh/imgdb/'
ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS = set(['jpg', 'jpeg'])

app = Flask(__name__)

app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_USER'] = 'root'
app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_PASSWORD'] = 'Abc@123def'
app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_DB'] = 'tamprint'
app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_HOST'] = 'localhost'
app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'] = UPLOAD_FOLDER
app.config['MAX_CONTENT_LENGTH'] = 100 * 1024 * 1024

mysql = MySQL()
mysql.init_app(app)


mysql = MySQL()
mysql.init_app(app)

@app.route('/julytest', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def get():
        print(request.files['image_data'])
        img = request.files['image_data']
        fil = img.filename
        w = 16.5
        h = 20.5
        l = w-0.25
        m = w-0.25
        p = h-0.25
        q = h-0.25
        image = cv2.imread(img.filename)
        #rows, cols, channels = image.shape
        #print(rows,cols,channels)
        cv2.imwrite(fil, image)
        cur = mysql.connect().cursor()
        #do other stuff
```

As i said before, this works perfectly for smaller images....but for larger images, i am not able to read them using OpenCV, which indicates that I am not receiving these images at the server end.

Answer (score 0):

If it's working on smaller images , why don't you try reading the file using chunks .
[how to use chunks](http://izmailoff.github.io/web/flask-file-streaming/)